# Is there a chain calling method in Python?

Tags: python

Is there a function in Python that would do this:

```
val = f3(f2(f1(arg)))
```

by typing this (for example):

```
val = chainCalling(arg,f3,f2,f1)
```

I just figured, since python is (arguably) a functional language the function I'm looking for will make syntax brighter

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [`reduce()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) to chain calls:

```
from functools import reduce

val = reduce(lambda r, f: f(r), (f1, f2, f3), arg)
```

I used the [forward-compatible `functools.reduce()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.reduce); in Python 3 `reduce()` is no longer in the built-in namespace.

This can also be made a separate function, of course:

```py
from functools import reduce

def chain(*funcs):
    def chained_call(arg):
        return reduce(lambda r, f: f(r), funcs, arg)

    return chained_call
```

Comment: you should link to https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html?highlight=reduce#functools.reduce instead of the v2 version

Comment: @zmo: the majority of people still use Python 2; without a specific version indicator in the question I link to the Python 2 documentation, and explain any differences between the versions where applicable.

Comment: well, you used the python3 version in your code, so either link to the v3 or to both (as you give two links) ;-)

Comment: @zmo: I gave a forward-compatible version, it exists in Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html?highlight=reduce#functools.reduce) functool — as Martijn briantly suggested, or you can write it yourself quite simply:

```
def chainCalling(arg, *funcs):
    if len(funcs) > 0:
        return chainCalling(funcs[0](arg), funcs[1:])
    return arg
```

or, as an alternative not using recursion — so not bound to the call stack limitation, as suggested by Martijn:

```
def chainCalling(arg, *funcs):
    result = arg
    for f in funcs:
        result = f(result)
    return result
```

Obviously, you'll want to call it that way, to avoid an useless reversal of the arguments:

```
chainCalling(arg, f1, f2, f3)
```

Comment: With enough functions, this'll hit the recursion limit. Why limit yourself to 1000 calls, tops? It's a loop, just use a loop. The `reduce()` documentation gives you a starting point.

Comment: Just suggesting an alternative solution, that's simple to write and understand, and pretty good for small list of functions. Though you're totally right that it has its limits

Comment: You're right, missed that he wanted the result returned, correcting the code

Comment: Also, their sample call reverses the functions, so you'd want to use `funcs[-1]` and `funcs[:-1]`. And my version would need to use `reversed(funcs)` in the loop.

Comment: As a note against `reduce`: [(sic)](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins) "*Use functools.reduce() if you really need it; however, 99 percent of the time an explicit for loop is more readable.*". Though I have to admit, I'm still a user of the reduce function when I consider it makes sense.

Comment: @Zetys the first code is just recursing over the `funcs` list, applying the "tip" of the list to `arg`, and keeping the "tail" of the list for n+1 call.

Comment: Personally I preffer to reuse and not invent, I think it is better in many cases. As for creating a function of my own, why won't I create chainCalling() by wrapping Martijn Pieters's solution - It is neater and depending on Python libs

Comment: Well, I just gave those options to make answers complete, in your case — which is quite simple — I'm not sure I'd actually use reduce, but I definitely use reduce quite often myself :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters You said ` 1000 calls`. can you give an example that chain 1000 method calls.

Comment: @Zetys: any system that programatically collects function calls into a list could end up doing this. [`collective.transmogrifier`](http://docs.plone.org/external/collective.transmogrifier/docs/source/transmogrifier.html) doesn't use `reduce()` but does chain up generators, and with pipeline reuse you could easily end up with close to a 1000 functions to bust your stack.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to apply the chain of functions to multiple arguments, you can create an aggregated function.

```
g = lambda x: f3(f2(f1(x)))
```

or more flexible (when there is an arbitrary list of functions):

```
from functools import reduce, partial

f3 = lambda x: -x
f2 = lambda x: x ** 2
f1 = lambda x: x + 1
function_list = (f1, f2, f3)
g = partial(reduce, lambda r, f: f(r), function_list)
print(g(3))  # results in -16
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a tad late, but try my solution below. `chain_func` essentially creates a new wrapper function that calls all underlying functions in chain when invoked in runtime.

```py
def chain_func(*funcs):
    def _chain(*args, **kwargs):
        cur_args, cur_kwargs = args, kwargs
        ret = None
        for f in reversed(funcs):
            cur_args, cur_kwargs = (f(*cur_args, **cur_kwargs), ), {}
            ret = cur_args[0]
        return ret

    return _chain
```

Comment: your function could be a good solution but it is not python by def

Comment: @ShaiBen-Dor what do you mean by "not python by def"? Code above works for python 3.

Comment: I mean that you invent the wheel, look at the correct answer, it uses python standard functions to achieve the goal. thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like these answers are correct, but do not address the spirit of the question. We can get the same behavior by creating an intermediate "chained" function definition, and we can avoid confusion about the meaning of nested labmdas by defining a function that produces the chained function.

I have used `g(f(x))` here so that the functions are applied from left to right.

```py
from functools import reduce
from typing import Iterable, Callable, Any

def chain_fns(fns: Iterable[Callable[[Any], Any]]) -> Callable[[Any], Any]:                                                                     
    return reduce(lambda f, g: lambda x: g(f(x)), fns)

chained_method = chain_fns([f1, f2, f3])
chained_method(arg)
```