# Chaining functions calls on some list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8

Let's say I have three functions and it needs to process a list one after another.

```
def f1(lst):
    lst_processed = do_something_of_type1(lst)
    return lst_processed

def f2(lst):
    lst_processed = do_something_of_type2(lst)
    return lst_processed

def f3(lst):
    lst_processed = do_something_of_type3(lst)
    return lst_processed
```

I would like to apply these three functions on some `input_list` in the following order: `f1`, then `f2` since `f2` needs the processed list from `f1` and finally `f3` which needs the return value of `f2`.

Option 1:

```
output_list = f3(f2(f1(input_list)))
```

Option 2:

```
   output_list1 = f1(input_list)
   output_list2 = f2(output_list1)
   output_list = f3(output_list2)
```

Does one of these comply with PEP 8 more so than the other?

Comment: Do you need three separate functions? Why not just have one that does all the processing? Or create a class where your can do method chaining.

Comment: @It_is_Chris I do need all three functions as I have divided different type of processing in them. Class might be too complex for such situation but of course that could be an option. I am just interested in choosing these two options.

Comment: I am also wondering why would be class method chaining preferred in this case over option 1?

Comment: It really is going to depend on your specific use. If it is something will will be used across multiple .py files and/or if you need to call the functions in a different order `f3(f1(input_list))` or some other variation. It may be easier to just do `Foo(input_list).f1().f3()`

Comment: The methods are used in different situations. In some cases, I will be using just f1, or f2 or f3 or f3.f2 or f2.f1 so they are bit different general purpose but my question was more about once one has such a specific situation in question, then which option is better.

Comment: I would question the function separation. If there is a valid reason to separate them. IIRC isnt it a Python antipattern to have linked dependencies unnecessarily?

Answer (score 2):

From this answer: [Is there a chain calling method in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34613543/is-there-a-chain-calling-method-in-python)

```
def f1(i):
    return i + 1


def f2(i):
    return i + 1


def f3(i):
    return i + 1


def f4(i):
    return i + 1


from functools import reduce


def chain(*funcs):
    def chained_call(arg):
        return reduce(lambda r, f: f(r), funcs, arg)

    return chained_call


chained = chain(f1, f2, f3, f4)

print(chained(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's actually anything built-in to do this (`functools` seemed like the most likely place to find something), but it's also relatively easy to write the kind of thing you'd find there

```
def chainfunc(funcs, arg):
    ret = arg
    for f in funcs:
        ret = f(arg)
    return ret

output_list = chainfunc([f1, f2, f3], lst)
```

That said, you can also coerce `functools.reduce()` into doing something like this in a one-liner:

```
from functools import reduce

output_list = reduce(lambda a, b: b(a), [f1, f2, f3], lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

option 1 is more pythonic, but depends for whom you are writing your code.
For my opinion option 2 is more readable for junior developers.
Have you searched the pep8 documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I would put option 2 in a function of it’s own, and then call that. Also, I wouldn’t call them `f1`, `f2`, etc.

Comment: f1, f2 etc is just for demonstration purposes :)

Answer (score -4):

Why do you need 3 functions?

```
def f(lst):
   lst_1 = do_something_of_type1(lst)
   lst_2 = do_something_of_type2(lst_1)
   lst_processed = do_something_of_type3(lst_2)
return lst_processed
```

Comment: I assume the functions are 1. not just useful in this context, and 2. split up for organization, etc.

Comment: Is this an attempt at answering the question? If so, please edit the answer to make it clear how this answers the question.